# how do i filter a array of objects to display only ids of the ones that have all existing type properties

Tags: arrays, object, filter, array-map

im getting data from an API that looks like this:

```
const flags = [
  {
    type: "manyCards",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: "manyCards",
    id: 2
  },
   {
    type: ":premiumCard",
    id: 1
  },
]
```

i want to filter/sort it so it displays only the ids that have all types eg. id:1 has both manyCards and premiumCard.

som my result would be `result = [1]` in this case.

Cant figure out what Array prototypes to use.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would group the initial data by id, so that we can know how many types each id has.

Once this is done, we can filter with any conditions we want.

```js
const flags = [
    {
        type: "manyCards",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        type: "manyCards",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        type: ":premiumCard",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        type: "manyCards",
        id: 3
    },
    {
        type: "manyCards",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        type: ":premiumCard",
        id: 3
    },
]

let grouped = flags.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.id] = r[a.id] || []
    r[a.id].push(a.type)
    return r
}, {})
let result = Object.keys(grouped).filter(elem => (grouped[elem].includes("manyCards") && grouped[elem].includes(":premiumCard")))

console.log(result)
```